# Effectively swap unique key column value spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

In one of my business use case i need to set priority of travel in which priority should not be **duplicate** and are in order.
i made rdbms(Oracle) table with priority as unique key.

| TRAVEL_TYPE_NAME | PRIORITY (UNIQUE KEY) |
| --- | --- |
| AIR | 1 |
| RAIL | 2 |
| ROAD | 3 |

After that, i want to **SWAP** the priority between them. let say, make Road travel - 2 and Rail travel - 3. By executing below code.

```
@Transactional
private void updatePriority(...){
    ...
    ...
    travelRepository.saveAll(updatedTravelEntities);
    ...
    ...
}
```

it throws exception **ORA-00001**: unique constraint (TRAVEL_PRIORITY.TRAVEL_PRIORITY_AK02).

i apply below code changes but same error observed.

```
@Transactional
private void updatePriority(...){
    ...
    ...
    travelRepository.deleteAll()
    travelRepository.saveAll(allEntities);
    ...
    ...
}
```

```
@Transactional
private void updatePriority(...){
    ...
    ...
    travelRepository.deleteAll()
    travelRepository.flush()
    travelRepository.saveAll(allEntities);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Can any one suggest, How should i effectively solve this use case.

Comment: You can give them random priority such a 6,5,7 and then save them.
and in next original method you can give them there real value and save original later.

its a work around but not solid solution.